# wordpress api make 2 custom post type with single request

Tags: wp-api

i have messenger chatbot and if the user click **Get Started**
i make **singel api call** with `$sender_id` as title to add new post to my CPT **inquery**
and when i look to wordpress panel i see 2 of them with same title and when make another api call with `$sender_id` as title it gives me the old one
i can't figure why it happend from beginning
Thanks in advenced

Comment: Hi, can you please share your code?

Comment: this id my costum end point                                                                              `function get_inquiry_id($data){
  $return = [];
  $title=$data['title'];

  $return = get_page_by_title($title, OBJECT, 'inquiry');
  $return = $return->ID;

 return new WP_REST_Response($return, 200);

}

add_action('rest_api_init',function(){
  register_rest_route('chatbot/v1','/inquiry/(?P<title>\d+)',array(
    'methods'=>'GET',
    'callback'=>'get_inquiry_id'
  ));
});`

Comment: and this is my code for if statment if **Get Started** clicked                                                                                                          `if ( $payload == 'firsthand' ) {

  $sender_id = ''.$sender_id.'';
  $data_array =
    array(
    "title"=>$sender_id
  )
  ;

    callAPI('POST','http://alenke.test/wp-json/wp/v2/inquiry',json_encode($data_array));`

Answer (score 0):

Please write function for get post by title

```
function get_page_by_post_title( $page_title, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        SELECT ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_title = %s
        AND post_type = %s 
        ORDER BY ID DESC
    ",
        $page_title,
        $post_type
    );

    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

    if ( $page ) {
        return get_post( $page, $output );
    }
}
```

And this is your inquire_id function like,

```
function get_inquiry_id($data){ 
    $return = []; 
    $title=$data['title']; 
    $return = get_page_by_post_title($title, OBJECT, 'inquiry'); 
    $return = $return->ID; 
    return new WP_REST_Response($return, 200); 
}
```

Comment: my problem is not getting the **ID of inquery**  my function return the id                    
But it is when i make **API Call with POST** method it execute twice like that            2115706638540570 — Draft                                                                     2115706638540570 — Draft